# C++ Trouble Overloading Operators - Class Assignment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've viewed multiple topics on stackoverflow and I'm not getting anywhere with this class assignment. I believe I'm using the code as it was presented in the book but I'm having problems with the = operator not copying and the - operator returning two values concatenated. I'm hoping you can help me understand and point me in the right direction on this. Any help is appreciated.

The rectangleType class has two protected members, length and width, and a function called rectangleType.area() that multiplies them. In the assignment, I'm supposed to change book code that returns length and width and return area instead but I can't get these to work right. (Relational and stream operators are working fine.)

From rectangleType.h:

```
rectangleType operator=(const rectangleType&) const; // replace one rectangle with another
rectangleType operator-(const rectangleType&) const; // subtract one rectangle from another
```

From rectangleTypeImp.cpp

```
rectangleType rectangleType::operator=(const rectangleType& rectangle) const
{
    rectangleType temp = *this;

    temp.length = rectangle.length;
    temp.width = rectangle.width;

    return temp;
}
rectangleType rectangleType::operator-(const rectangleType& rectangle) const
{
    rectangleType temp = *this;

    if(temp.length - rectangle.length >= 1 && temp.width - rectangle.width >= 1)
    {
        temp.length = temp.length - rectangle.length;
        temp.width = temp.width - rectangle.width;

        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Dimensions are not large enough."
             << "Cancelling operation and returning dimensions"
             << "of left operand." << endl;
    }

    return temp;    
}
```

In the main file, I have created the following objects:

```
rectangleType myOtherYard(26, 19);
rectangleType myBrothersYard(2, 2);
rectangleType myMothersYard(3, 3);
```

and written this code:

```
myOtherYard = myBrothersYard;
cout << endl << "myOtherYard = myBrothersYard: " 
     << myOtherYard;
cout << endl << "myBrothersYard - myMothersYard: " 
     << myBrothersYard + myMothersYard;
```

Here's the output I get (using formatted printing):

```
myOtherYard = myBrothersYard:   26.0019.00 
myBrothersYard - myMothersYard: 3.003.00
```

It looks like there is no assignment going on in the = operator and it's returning the length and width of the first object without change. Also, the - operator seems to be doing its job but returning length and width separately and I don't know how to get it to return the area. Everything I've tried in code has failed.

The + operator adds and returns separate length and width values. It does look like it's adding them correctly.

Any way you can help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of your `operator=`, you are not changing the object on the "receiving" end, but changing and returning a temporary. This is not correct. (Also, `operator=` should not be `const`, since by its nature changes the object!).

Comment: Yes, I started using temp because I couldn't get length = rectangle.length and width = rectangle.width to work.

Awesome! I got the = to work by removing const, removing temp and returning *this! THANK YOU!

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: It wouldn't assign the values but it does now. Now, I just have to figure out how to get it to return the area instead of separate length and width. :-)

Comment: Don't use `endl` twice in one function.  It means `'\n'` then `std::flush`, so just put `'\n'` where you don't need to flush output.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that and the teacher never said anything to me about it. I will be sure to change my habits there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your assignment operation should return a reference to yourself.  It should not be const either, since you are assigning to yourself.  See many references, mainly Scott Meyers "Effective C++", for reasoning.

Since you are just learning, and I don't see it in there, I assume you are not supposed to know about move semantics, so I'll leave that out...

Assignment operator from another rectangle...

```
rectangleType &
rectangleType::
operator=(rectangleType const & that)
{
    length = that.length;
    width = that.width;

    return *this;
}
```

However, it looks like the default assignment operator would be sufficient.  If you are required to write the assignment operator for class, I imagine you also have to write the copy constructor as well.

If you are going to have an `operator-` you should also have `operator-=`.  Again, consult Meyers for lots of explanation.

On your subtraction implementation... Egads.  Really?  cout for an error?  and then return an object that is not the right answer?

Comment: Thanks! You are correct that I do not know about move semantics. 

I forgot to do a -= operator but it should be easy to do once I get this straightened out. Thanks for mentioning that, and I'll do += as well.

On my subtraction implementation, I plead guilty but ask for your indulgence. Malik's examples are returning text that has nothing to do with the data in the object that I'm dealing with and the assignment asks you to return an error message. :-)

Comment: I got most of it fixed. Now, I just can't figure out why my multiplication and division operators (using the same code but changing to * and /) aren't giving the right results when I return the area. (sigh) So much to learn! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't mind helping with homework, if it's marked as such.  You should implement `+=` and such, then implement the operators in terms of it.  It's actually hard to imagine adding and subtracting rectangles, but it's even much more difficult to imagine what multiplying and dividing rectangles should be.  Maybe you want to multiply and divide by a scalar instead of another rectangle.  Also, throwing an exception is a good way of saying "you have asked me to do something impossible and I can't even return a reasonable value.:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As a non-traditional (read as: older) college student, I realize that getting someone to do your homework for you robs you of the learning experience. I try to be careful to only come here with homework when I'm really stuck, like this time, or just needing a bit of advice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that may help:

```
rectangleType& rectangleType::operator=(const rectangleType& rectangle) 
{
    if (this != &rectangle)
    {
         length = rectangle.length;
         width = rectangle.width;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I have always though that the self-assignent check is just useless. Consider the situations when someone do that. Very few. Of course this opinion could be viewed as subjective.

Comment: I was wondering about that. I think I was also getting a little wonky with the code in desperation because I didn't realize that const was my biggest problem. I'm changing it now and things are starting to work. :-)

Comment: Much, much better now! Thanks for helping! Just trying to figure out why * and / overloads using the same code for a base aren't giving expected results. You would think that length = length / rectangle.length and doing the same with width would result in an area of the returned length * width but it's acting wonky.

(sigh) So much to learn! I'm glad I enjoy this!

Comment: Self-assignment check is probably useless here, but in more complex scenarios it may help preventing overlapped memory copying. I would consider this check as a part of the pattern...